# My background image isn't fully shown

Tags: image

I tried changing some view setting, but it did not solve anything. Is there any reason why my background image doesn't fully appear like this image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try to set **Depth** in image settings to default:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Crantisz, i has tried to solved this problem for a day, seriously. and it's done just for few minutes after i post it. thanks a lot for your help, it's really helpful to me